# Unable to clone All-Projects repo after Gerrit install

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a newly setup instance of Gerrit

Currently there are only two repos:
All-Projects
binutils-test

When attempting to clone All-Projects I receive the following error:

```
git clone  ssh://user@hostname:29418/All-Projects
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/
error: Trying to write ref HEAD with nonexistant object 2055f748c7285720057fe7213258e6c5b11776e3
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
```

Cloning of the other repository (binutils-test) works OK, so at least the basic setup seems OK. My user is a member of the Administators group, and so shouldn't have any access issues.

My end goal is cloning All-Projects so I can modify the project.config to add the Verified label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [blog](http://blog.bruin.sg/?p=171) provides details on how to add the "Verified Label" in the project.config and that required you to modify the All-Projects projects.

Answer (score 6):

After posting a similar question to the gerrit mailing list (repo-discuss), I got the following instructions.
These at least act as a workaround and enabled me to edit the project.config and push the changes back to gerrit.
I now have a working "verified" label.

```
$ git init cfg ; cd cfg
$ git remote add origin ssh://user@hostname:29418/All-Projects
$ git pull origin refs/meta/config
$ vi project.config
$ git commit -a -m 'Updated permissions'
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/config
```

this is described in
http://www.eclipsecon.org/2013/sites/eclipsecon.org.2013/files/Deploying%20Gerrit%20Code%20Review.pdf

Comment: This is also helpful when you import a gerrit database from another instance and have to re-associate the Administrators group ID with the one you imported.  In my case, I logged into the gerrit server via SSH and pulled from the file system:  `git remote add origin "/home/gerrit2/gerrit/git/All-Projects.git"`.  The group id is in the file *groups*.