# Can't find 'Label Verified' permission in gerrit 2.7

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I'm trying to configure Jenkins gerrit trigger following this instructions: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger. One point says to grant 'Label verified' permission to Non-intractive users. The problem is, I don't see such a privilege...

'Add permission...' combo box has 'Label Code-review' permission but not 'Label verified'.

Was this permission removed/renamed from gerrit 2.7? Will this plugin work if I don't set it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed the "Verified label" was removed. You need to add it to the project.config which is not as straight forward as it sounds. More info on how to add it to your project.config can be found in this [blog](http://blog.bruin.sg/?p=171) post as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884632/2259878) before

Comment: It`s work with "[How to edit the project.config for all projects in Gerrit | Notes and more](http://blog.bruin.sg/2013/04/how-to-edit-the-project-config-for-all-projects-in-gerrit/)", thank you!

Comment: Another option is to remove --verified <VERIFIED> from gerrit-trigger plugin configuration so 'verified' label won't be posted.

Comment: Wouldn't the removing of `--verified <VERIFIED>` also remove the feed back that was wanted in the first place?

Comment: For any person about to implement this solution, I had to restart Gerrit (2.15) to have it accept the "Verified" label.

Answer (score 6):

In Gerrit version 2.12, I was able to re-add "Label Verified" by changing the All Project Config via the GUI.

Steps:

1. Selecting Projects => List => All Projects => General
2. Clicking the Edit Config button under the Project Commands section
3. Adding the following block at the bottom and clicking

`[label "Verified"]
        function = MaxWithBlock
        value = -1 Fails
        value =  0 No score
        value = +1 Verified`

4. Click the Save and Close button
5. Click the Publish button
6. Click the Code Review +2 button
7. Click the Submit button

Answer (score 4):

Yes this label was removed from the default installation of Gerrit 2.7.  If you had an earlier installation and upgrade to 2.7 you will still have the label.  The plugin will still work - you can [add the verified label](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.7/config-labels.html#label_Verified) to your Gerrit setup or configure the plugin to use the code reviewe label (or any other custom label).