# Adding gerrit label, but not able to see it properly in review page

Tags: gerrit

Using gerrit 2.9. I am new to gerrit configuration and am trying to add a *Verified* label to the All-projects project so that the verified label is shown in the reviews for all projects.  The relevant part of the `project.config` looks like this:

```
[label "Code-Review"]
    function = MaxWithBlock
    copyMinScore = true
    value = -2 This shall not be merged
    value = -1 I would prefer this is not merged as is
    value =  0 No score
    value = +1 Looks good to me, but someone else must approve
    value = +2 Looks good to me, approved
[label "Verified"]
    value = -1 Fails
    value =  0 No score
    value = +1 Verified
```

I run the following commands:

```
$ git commit -am "Add verified label"
$ git push -f origin meta/config:meta/config
```

Now, when I go and try to review a change-set, I see the *needs verified* line, but I don't see anywhere that I can place it.  The screen looks like this:

[image: Review page does not allow you to verify]

There is no way for me to set verified on the review.

I had help from this question: [Can't find 'Label Verified' permission in gerrit 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019195/cant-find-label-verified-permission-in-gerrit-2-7)  but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you granted yourself permission to set the Verified label?

Comment: Most likely, I have not.  How would I do that?

Comment: This is most likely the problem then. Writing up an answer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have sufficient permissions to set the Verified label. In Gerrit, all change scoring must be explicitly allowed. If you don't have permissions to set a label, it won't even appear in the Publish view.

To grant users permission to set the Verified label, locate the project you want to affect (or, perhaps more likely, the special All Projects project to have it apply everywhere). On the Access tab, choose Edit. Under refs/heads/*, add a "Label Verified" permission and assign a suitable group. If there's no refs/heads/* reference in the list, add it.