# manual gerrit review cmd did not update "verified" label value

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit

we are trying to setup jenkins and gerrit for CI framework, gerrit can trigger Jenkins build, but can not update gerrit's verified label after build success, so i tried with manual command, still failed to update gerrit verified label field via following ssh command on jenkins server, but can update code-review label.

```
    ssh -p 29418 gfkfcmo@cmgerrit1.com gerrit review -p HiCloud/myProject --label Verified=1 --code-review +1 27263,1
```

1.Setup:

gerrit:2.8.1   Jenkins: 2.60 gerrit trigger:2.27

2. Gerrit change:

2.1 update myProject's project.config to enable verified label.

```
    [label "Verified"]
    function = MaxWithBlock
    value = -1 Fails
    value =  0 No score
    value = +1 Verified
```

2.2 adding gfkfcmo as Jenkins non-interactive user, add permission in myProject access:
        Reference: refs/*
        Read: ALLOW for Non-Interactive Users

```
    Reference: refs/heads/*
    Label Code-Review: -1, +1 for Non-Interactive Users
    Label Verified: -1, +1 for Non-Interactive Users
```

3. Jenkins change.
   3.1 add gerrit server info, so "Trigger a Gerrit event manually" on jenkins works well.
   3.2 Gerrit's comment add can also trigger Jenkins job build, so the conn works well.
4. But build result was not posted back to gerrit, so using above SSH command on jenkins server, I can update "code-review" with user gfkfcmo, but did not take effect on "verified" label, see picture below.

I searched on this topic but did not get any hint or answers.  Any hint will be highly appreciated.

[updated screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUR0i.png)

[update screen with "tested" label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oWi7.png)

Comment: issue was solved after adding "ref/*" Non-interactive user access, Jenkins can post vote via SSH for verified label.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "--verified +1" option is only available if the "Verified" label is defined in the "All-Projects" root project. In your case you need to use the "--label Label-Name=N" option:

```
ssh -p 29418 gfkfcmo@cmgerrit1.com gerrit review -p HiCloud/myProject --label Verified=+1 --code-review +1 27263,1
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, do change to "tested" label, but still the same. see picture as attached in my questions, can not update "tested" label via SSH command.

Comment: Have you used the "--label Tested=+1" review option when you tried to update the "Tested" label?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set Verified flag with --verified +1, i.e.

```
ssh -p 29418 gfkfcmo@cmgerrit1.com gerrit review -p HiCloud/myProject --verified +1 --code-review +1 27263,1
```

Comment: thanks for echo, but gerrit will complain not valid if using "--verified +1", see output below: # ssh -p 29418 gfkfcmo@cmgerrit1.com gerrit review -p HiCloud/myProject --verified +1 --code-review +2 27263,1
fatal: "--verified" is not a valid option

Comment: What if:  --label Verified=+1 ?

Comment: thanks dxr3x.  "Veified=+1“ still does not work, the problem is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478344/adding-gerrit-label-but-not-able-to-see-it-properly-in-review-page  , i can not edit verified label on gerrit UI, even with permission.  Based on googling, may similar as https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/ATuxFWiaQcA,  i only update one project config file, not All-Projects' config, just my suspect but did not tried yet as this is  company's gerrit server.

Comment: Another hypothesis is that you used a wrong format in project.config [access] section...

In my project this is like the following:

`[access "refs/*"]
    label-Verified = -1..+1 group NF: repo-1: Developer`

PS. It worth to mention that we use Gerrit 2.14

Comment: thanks for the hint, after adding accessing in  "refs/*" Jenkins can post vote for verified label now. i can not vote for your answer now. thanks again.