# Update access rights in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have made changes to the project.config for All_Projects . When saving the results I click "Save for Review" (I am not allowed to save it directly). It works ok and I get a review in Gerrit where everything looks ok. I then set code review +2 but then I am not able to set Verified +1. 
When looking in the project.config file it looks like this:

```
[access "refs/meta/config"]
    exclusiveGroupPermissions = read
    read = group Administrators
    read = group Project Owners
    push = group Administrators
    push = group Project Owners
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Administrators
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Project Owners
    submit = group Administrators
    submit = group Project Owners
```

So the verifed possibility is missing. But since I can not submit my changes I can not change it to something like this

```
[access "refs/meta/config"]
    exclusiveGroupPermissions = read
    read = group Administrators
    read = group Project Owners
    push = group Administrators
    push = group Project Owners
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Administrators
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Project Owners
    submit = group Administrators
    submit = group Project Owners
    label-Verified = -1..+1 group Administrators
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: Did you do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019195/cant-find-label-verified-permission-in-gerrit-2-7/20027953#20027953

Comment: Yes, I read that but as descibed in my comment to the answer below I had problems with access rights and thought that I was doing something wrong. But know I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually add the change to have the Verified option. You may follow the below options:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git init
git remote add origin ssh://admin@remote.site.com:29418/All-Projects
git fetch origin refs/meta/config:refs/remotes/origin/meta/config
git checkout meta/config
```

No you will be able to see **project.config** file. Keep the below block to that file:

```
[label "Verified"]
       value = -1 Fails
       value =  0 No score
       value = +1 Verified
```

Now commit and push this change to remote.

```
git commit -a
git push origin meta/config:meta/config
```

That's all, now you will be able to see the **Verified** option as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this way but got some problems with the access to the git but when solved I managed to do as described above, withthe only difference that I went directly to the git with /home/gerrit2/instalation...../All-Projects

It was not the "Verified" part that was missing in my case but it was project.config file that needded to have this added.

 label-Verified = -1..+1 group Administrators