# Unable to set up "Sonar Gerrit" Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I am trying to set up [Sonar Gerrit - Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+Gerrit#SonarGerrit-Gerrit) on a Jenkins job.

**Context**

1. A Jenkins job is launched when a patch set is created to Gerrit
2. Source are pulled with git, cppcheck analysis is launched and a sonar analysis is launched on preview mode.
3. Post-Build action "Post SonarQube issues as Gerrit comments" is launched.

Here are the Jenkins analysis logs for the third point.

```
Getting Sonar Report from: [XX].sonar\sonar-report.json
Report has loaded and contains 2950 issues
Connected to Gerrit: server name: Gerrit. Change Number: 297, PatchSetNumber: 1
Unable to post review: Request failed.
Build step 'Post SonarQube issues as Gerrit comments' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

A comment is added to Gerrit (meaning the communication works)

> Build Failed
>   http:jenkins.com/job/project/118/ : FAILURE

I am not able to understand where the configuration is not right. Do you know this issue ?

On Gerrit `httpd_log` file I have following lines when I launched a new Jenkins job.

> IP **- -** [26/oct./2016:14:30:08 +0200] "POST /a/changes/REF/revisions/REF/review HTTP/1.1" 401 12 - "Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_20)"
>
> IP **- jenkins** [26/oct./2016:14:30:08 +0200] "POST /a/changes/REF/revisions/REF/review HTTP/1.1" 200 24 - "Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_20)"

On first command, there is none user instead on the second one there is `jenkins` user. This user is used to connect Jenkins server to Gerrit server (both ssh and REST API). Is it this the issue ?

---

What I tried so far

**Reconfigure Gerrit Trigger Plugin under Jenkins**

As [@Marcelo](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+Gerrit#SonarGerrit-Gerrit) mentioned, Sonar Gerrit plugins uses Gerrit trigger. I reconfigure the entire plugin following [Gerrit trigger set up](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-SetupRequirements).

I previously missed the step under adding Gerrit access rights for "Label Verified"

> Admin > Projects > ... > Access > Edit
>
> Reference: refs/heads/* Label : Verified: -1, +1 for Non-Interactive Users

Detailed explanation on post [Can't find 'Label Verified' permission in gerrit 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20019195/2394026).

**Remove verified tag send from Jenkins to Gerrit**
As explained in [install documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-NotetoGerrit%3E2.6Users) for Gerrit > 2.7.

> Go to "Manage Jenkins" and click the "Gerrit Trigger" link
>
> Under "Gerrit Servers" next to your server(s) click the "Edit" button (looks
>   like a gear, other icons may overlap it)
>
> Under "Gerrit Reporting Values" click the Advanced button at the bottom
>
> Under "Gerrit Verified Commands" remove the '--verified ' sections from each command

---

**Software Version**

- Jenkins 2.19.1 *Git (2.5.3), Gerrit Trigger (2.21.1), SonarQube (2.4.4), Sonnar Gerrit (1.0.6) plugins. Note: Gerrit Trigger Rest API is functional*
- SonarQube 5.5
- Gerrit 2.12.2. *Events-Log plugin installed (default configuration)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's a issue with your REST API connection between Jenkins and Gerrit.

The "Sonar Gerrit" plugin uses the "Gerrit Trigger" plugin to post messages in Gerrit. The "Gerrit Trigger" plugin can use two different methods to post messages in Gerrit: SSH or REST API.

The "Build Failed ... FAILURE" message is posted directly by "Gerrit Trigger" plugin and it can be performed using SSH. The "Sonar Gerrit" messages CAN'T be performed using SSH, they need to be done using REST API so the "Gerrit Trigger" plugin needs to be configured to use REST API to enable "Sonar Gerrit" plugin to post in Gerrit.

See more info [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+Gerrit#SonarGerrit-Gerrit).

Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Gerrit Trigger > Edit > Advanced

And check if the REST API is enabled and if it's working as expected (using the "Test REST Connection" button)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I didn't mention it on my question (I edited now) but REST API is correctly enable. Restarting Jenkins doesn't change anything. Is there a way to test Rest API message ?

Comment: Have you used the "Test REST Connection" button at the "Gerrit Trigger" configuration?

Comment: Yes and it works. It says "Success". Waiting for other hints, I will try to reconfigure the entire plugin

Comment: This is really weird... the change in Gerrit is not closed, is it?

Comment: No it's not. I updated my question with all I tried for 2 days.

Comment: Why are you not using Sonar Gerrit plugin 2.4.4 (latest)? FYI I don't see any issue with that but we're running out of options...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126344/discussion-between-flows-and-marcelo-avila-de-oliveira).

Comment: Sorry... my mistake... I mean: Why are you not using Gerrit Trigger plugin 2.22.0 (latest)?

Comment: Another things to check: I saw "Report has loaded and contains 2950 issues" in your output... will this result in 2950 comments in Gerrit? Maybe there's a limit for the number of comments. Have you set the "Filter Settings" options on the "Post SonarQube issues as Gerrit comments" section of the Jenkins job? Check also the "Gerrit Settings"  section: there's a "Post score?" option... are you posting score? If yes, be sure that the REST user has permission to do that.

Comment: Have you checked the items I listed in the previous post?

Comment: Yes I do, but all seems right. The option "Report new issues only" is checked. I post the score and REST API is correctly configured.

Comment: Did you check if the Jenkins user has Gerrit permission to vote?

Comment: The jenkins user is able to vote, but it set the vote to -1. I assumed this is because the job is detected as FAILED. Did you see the httpd_log I quote ? Is it normal ?

Comment: Yes, I think the -1 vote was given by Gerrit Trigger because the job failed at the end. I found the same behaviour in my httpd log. Have you correctly set the "Category" in "Gerrit Settings" section of the Sonar Gerrit plugin in the Jenkins job? This is really hard... take a look at the Gerrit error_log file too.

Comment: I gave you my bounty since you really tried to help me. It seems to be a REST API issue as mentioned [there](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32851)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let's wait for [JENKINS-32851](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32851).

Answer (score 1):

Does it work with section "post score?" Unchecked?

What category do you use for score posting? (Have you created it in Gerrit?)

If I remember correctly, an exception (provided by Gerrit Trigger) causing message

> Unable to post review: Request failed.

is always exactly the same and doesn't help to understand the reason of `RestApiException` anyway.

Comment: Checkout the new 1.0.7 version for extra logging.

Comment: The extra logging are relevant and show me the issue comes from connection. The problems still open but it is not link to your plugin

Answer (score 1):

a new version of sonar-gerrit plugin has been released. I'm sorry for the delay.

I can't completely fix the problem [JENKINS-32851](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32851) right now as reasons of the exception may vary, but I have added an ability to see the RestAPIException stacktrace. See details in the project [Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+Gerrit#SonarGerrit-Pluginfailsbuildwithmessage%22Unabletopostreview.Requestfailed%22).
Please let me know if it helps (or not) and what (was?) causing your problem. I feel like I have to add some possible reasons of the exception to the troubleshooting section of the project Wiki :)