# How to create gerrit user?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gerrit

I want to create a Gerrit user named `jenkins` in order to use it for Jenkins jobs trigger by Gerrit.

My goal is to set up a environment as described in the post : [Unable to set up “Sonar Gerrit” Jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40157708/2394026)

As described on the [documentation](https://review.cyanogenmod.org/Documentation/cmd-create-account.html), I launched the command with `gerrit` user on the server hosting Gerrit (Gerrit instance is launched with `gerrit` user).

```
ssh -p 29418 localhost gerrit create-account --group "'Non-Interactive Users'" --ssh-key - jenkins
```

The command returns (same if I launch `ssh -p 29418 localhost`)

> Permission denied (publickey).

I am pretty sure it's a ssh configuration issue but I am not able to figured out what I missed. Do you have any clues ?

Comment: I think you're not executing the command you've posted. This command would result in "Gerrit Code Review: me: not found"! Are you trying to execute the "gerrit create-account" Gerrit command?

Comment: I failed my copy paste, my post is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Permission denied (publickey)" means that your SSH authentication to execute the "gerrit create-account" command was not successful.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-permission-denied.html).

Comment: Ok, the issue was I had to specify the user for ssh connection. Thanks for your hint. correct command is `ssh -p 29418 user@localhost gerrit create-account ... `