# gerrit jenkins integration issue by using sonar gerrit plugin

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

Gerrit-Trigger plugin is able to post comment on Gerrit dashboard , but sonar-gerrit plugin is not posting comments and getting error depicted below:

Gerrit-Trigger plugin:2.23

Gerrit:2.7

Sonar-Gerrit plugin:2.0

sonarQube: 5.6

Jenkins:2.32

**Jenkins Job  Level Log**

ERROR: Step ‘Post SonarQube issues as Gerrit comments’ failed: Unable to post review: Request not successful. Message: Server Error. Status-Code: 500. Content: Internal server error.
Finished: FAILURE

**Jenkins System log:**

Getting Sonar Report from: /opt/jenkinsnew/workspace/sonargerrit/.sonar/sonar-report.json

May 17, 2017 8:22:45 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.sonargerrit.SonarToGerritPublisher logMessage

Report has loaded and contains 213 issues

May 17, 2017 8:22:45 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.sonargerrit.SonarToGerritPublisher logMessage

Connected to Gerrit: server name: GBProjectnewserver. Change Number: 168, PatchSetNumber: 1

May 17, 2017 8:22:45 PM SEVERE org.jenkinsci.plugins.sonargerrit.SonarToGerritPublisher perform

Unable to post review: Request not successful. Message: Server Error. Status-Code: 500. Content: Internal server error.
com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.HttpStatusException: Request not successful. Message: Server Error. Status-Code: 500. Content: Internal server error.
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.throwHttpStatusException(GerritRestClient.java:467)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.checkStatusCodeError(GerritRestClient.java:454)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.checkStatusCodeServerError(GerritRestClient.java:447)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.checkStatusCode(GerritRestClient.java:433)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.request(GerritRestClient.java:227)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.requestRest(GerritRestClient.java:163)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.requestRest(GerritRestClient.java:155)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.requestJson(GerritRestClient.java:132)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.GerritRestClient.getRequest(GerritRestClient.java:101)
    at com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest.http.changes.RevisionApiRestClient.files(RevisionApiRestClient.java:168)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sonargerrit.SonarToGerritPublisher.perform(SonarToGerritPublisher.java:268)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)

Comment: There's an error on the Gerrit side. Have you checked its logs?

Comment: ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet : Error in GET /a/changes/171/revisions/1/files
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.google.gerrit.server.change.Patches.list(Patches.java:41)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:242)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that log snippet. Not all potential answerers bother with the comment thread.

Comment: Do you use REST API for communication between Jenkins and Gerrit? You can check this in Manage Jenkins -> Gerrit trigger -> [Edit button on your gerrit server] -> Advanced (on the bottom) -> "Use REST API" checkbox ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40157708/2394026